# Ruby Faker::Name.unique validation failed

Tags: ruby

I have a simple factory where I create categories with unique names

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :category do
    name_en Faker::Name.unique.first_name
  end
end
```

And in my spec files, I use this to create categories as such:

```
create_list(:category,2)
```

Now my problem is, I keep getting:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid Exception: Validation failed: Name en has already been taken
```

If I debug and try to call `Faker::Name.unique.first_name` myself, it shows a unique name for each call. Using `create(:category)` however shows the error seen above. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Use `sequence` for name_en field for uniq names

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :category do
    sequence :name_en, 'AAA0' do |sr|
      "#{Faker::Name.first_name}#{sr}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer. I upvoted this because it's helpful but didn't mark it correct as honestly this is not what I'm looking for. Trying to find why unique does not work 
Would be amazing if you have an idea :D :D